# How to migrate content from Documentum WebTop to Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, documentum, opencmis, webtop

I want to migrate content with metadata from Documentum WebTop to Alfresco.
Can anyone please help me with the possible ways and some basic steps if possible.

For the moment I can think about using apache chemistry open CMIS API to connect to both repository and migrate content.

But is there any other simplest way available? or is there any tool available that we can use as is with slight modifications?

Your inputs will be really helpfull.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 4):

The *simplest* way possible is to use CMIS to read from Documentum and write to Alfresco, especially if you don't already know anything about Documentum. That way you only have to learn one API.

This assumes your version of Documentum supports CMIS.

If you have a high volume of data to move you will probably end up implementing some sort of queue or streaming approach, as Miki suggests. But that still doesn't require you to write DFC code unless CMIS falls short in some area.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Potts. Can you please provide any sample code to get Documentum repository session object.  Rest I will manage. Please do the needful

Comment: I haven't used Documentum in years but the Apache Chemistry web site has many examples, including this page that shows how to create a session: http://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/create-session/index.html. You will need to know Documentum's CMIS service URL. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: We've been using Documentum CMIS for some projects in production, it can be used for this subject, that's for sure. Documentum CMIS comes as standalone webapp, it isn't part of core installation AFAIK, there is no default URL for it.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways.

Easiest way could be using middle layer migration app/toolkit/platform and implement DFC client for reading to middle layer from Documentum. 
On the write side of your middle layer you could easily use client that could consume REST api at the Alfresco target environment.

We've done this using Kafka as a middle layer using source & sink connectors (Confluent).

Comment: Hi @Miki , Thanks for the reply, but one problem here is I am not familiar with Documentum tools, and I don't have any knowledge of DFC . I am having experties at Alfresco end. So can you provide some sample code spinets and steps from documentum end. I will manage at alfresco end. Thanks.................

Comment: There are few bad structured samples on the web since Documentum is closed community with most helpful resources reserved for users of partnership program. Try googling around but dion0t expect much